# page.php is loading wordpress post instead of single.php

Tags: wordpress

I am very new to wordpress. So facing this issue. In my wordpress blog, I don't know why page.php is loading single wordpress post instead of single.php.

I have following content in page.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_content();
    endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer();
```

single.php:

```
<?php
/* The file for displaying single posts */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="blog-heading">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section class="blog-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <?php $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );
                    if ( ! empty( $featured_image_url ) ) { ?>
                        <div class="blog-item-thumbnail single">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            <div class="blog-item-date">
                                <?php the_time('m'); ?><br>
                                <span><?php the_time('M'); ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="blog-item-date single">
                            <?php the_time('m'); ?><br>
                            <span><?php the_time('M'); ?></span>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="blog-item-info">
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i><?php the_category(', '); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="blog-single-nav row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 blog-single-nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Prev'); ?></div>                     
                        <div class="col-sm-8 addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 blog-single-nav-next"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog-single-content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog-single-nav row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 blog-single-nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Prev'); ?></div>                     
                        <div class="col-sm-8 addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 blog-single-nav-next"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog-single-author row">          
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                            <?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail() ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-9">
                            <h5>About <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?></h5>
                            <p><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog-single-comments">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[fbcomments width="100%" count="off" num="5"]'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 blog-sidebar">
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Whenever I load a single post on a url http://www.example.com/blog/my-test-post/, the page.php is being employed, NOT single.php. I can't find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting.

Try...

1. Disable all plugins and see if the problem still exists.
2. Go to **Settings** -> **Permalinks** and hit the **Save Changes** button, again see if the problem still exists.
3. Remove page.php from your theme and see what happens. Does it 404 or does it use single.php

These are just some basic troubleshooting tips that might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I tried everything including what you suggested here. If I remove page.php, then index.php shows the single post. One important thing did you notice in my single.php file? Is the template structure ok?